# How to set pre-selected value in vue js dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on two `vue` component.sending `parent` component `array` data to `child` component using `props`.now i want to set `pre-selected` value in `child` component dropdownlist.

Here is my code sample:

```
props:{
  // pre-selected value based on this.
  userdata:{
    type:[Array,Object],
    required:true,
  },
  roles:{
    type:[Array,Object],
    required:true,
  },

},

data(){
  return{
   mutableRoles:[],

  }
},
```

and this is my view part:

```
//i want set pre-selected value on this dropdownlist
<select multiple v-model="mutableRoles" class="form-control">
         <option v-for="(role,index) in roles" v-bind:value="role.id" >{{role.name}}</option>
       </select>
```

> I have seen many example where show only using string. but in my case both are array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const CurrentRole = Vue.component("current-role", {
  template: `
    <div>
      <label>Options</label>
      <select v-model="roleId" @change="changeValue">
        <option v-for="v in roles" :key="v.id" :value="v.id">{{v.title}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    userdata: {
      type: [Array, Object],
      required: true,
    },
    roles: {
      type: [Array, Object],
      required: true,
    }
  },
  data: _ => ({
    roleId: null
  }),
  methods: {
    changeValue() {
      this.userdata.role = this.roles.find(e => e.id == this.roleId)
    },
  },
  mounted() { // for initial state
    this.roleId = this.userdata.role.id
  },
  watch: {
    userdata(v) { // for changes on parent
      if (v) this.roleId = v.role.id
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    rlist: [{
      id: 1,
      title: "a"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      title: "b"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      title: "c"
    }],
    user: {
      role: {
        id: 3,
        title: "c"
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeUser() {
      this.user = {
        role: {
          id: 1,
          title: "a"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.22/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>User: {{user}}</p>
  <current-role :userdata="user" :roles="rlist">
    </current-role/>
    <button @click="changeUser">change user</button>
</div>
```

The select is tailored for primitive values, therefore you'll need to add helper functions.

Higher level vue frameworks such as [vue-material](https://vuematerial.io/), [vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/), [element](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US) and [muse-ui](https://muse-ui.org/#/en-US) tend to offer components to cope with such problems with a higher abstraction level.

EDIT:

I changed the snippet in order to make it closer to your situation.

Comment: I want to do some like that. `<select multiple v-model="mutableRoles" class="form-control">    //v-for="userrole in userdata"                                                                                                        
         <option v-for="(role,index) in roles" v-bind:value="role.id" :selected="role.id===userrole.id" >{{role.name}}</option>
       </select>`

Comment: Hi @Gabrielle i change the snippet i hope it helps more